# Empty DataFrame creation: dtype changes if index is specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to create an empty dataframe storing unsigned 8-bit integers. If I specify the index, the dtype is automatically casted to `float64`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'], index=['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=np.uint8).dtypes
a    float64
b    float64
c    float64
dtype: object
```

If the index is not specified it works as I expected:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=np.uint8).dtypes
a    uint8
b    uint8
c    uint8
dtype: object
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This looks like a bug, check if it's already been filed: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues, if not, then submit an issue. It looks like it's upcasting the dtypes when you override the default index type from an Int64 to your passed values, it shouldn't do this

Comment: I'm not able to find the same exact bug there, but it might be closely related to [this one](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/30870)

Comment: I think this is different, but may have the same underlying cause, here you have an empty dataframe, there is no reindexing going or overwriting of index values, I see no reason why this should behave like this. I would submit a new issue.

Comment: Thinking about this, this may not be a bug, because you pass an index the `DataFrame` has to have some type of values to represent the missing values, so `NaN` values forces the `dtype` to `float64` in this case

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right. If you create the dataframe using `pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'], index=['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=np.uint8, data=np.zeros([3,3]))` the dtype stays uint8. Thanks! I think I'm going to close the post